# How to insert gaps between rows?

Tags: ng2-smart-table

i want to have gaps between rows in my ng2-smart-table,
`border-spacing` doesn't work.

i've tried to use `ng-deep` by following answer
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/504#issuecomment-395478716
but it doesn't work.
other styles work, but not this one.

```
::ng-deep{
  .dark-table { // set a selector
      display: table;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 6px;
      border-color: red;
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `border-collapse: separate;`